# Two way data binding for html contents in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some content coming from the server. I want to bind it a model variable using angularjs.

Suppose i'm getting the following from the server.

```
<html>
  <body>    
    <div id="post">
      <div id="post-id">123</div>
      <div id="post-author">Shahal</div>
      <div id="post-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, tempora.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to create a model variable `post` with the contents of appropriate fields in it. It's not possible with `ngBind` as its only `scope-->view` one way binding. And i can't use `ngModel`.Please help.

Comment: why can't you use ng-model again?

Comment: @gion_13 i dont wanna put those data in input fields. Isn't there no other way out?

Comment: If you want it do be a **two way** data binding, it means that you expect the view to be able to modify the model. If you don't want to use form inputs... how exactly would the user alter the data?

Comment: @gion_13 To be precise, i want a `view-->scope` binding, without using `ngModel`.

Comment: So at some point in your code you get the `<html/>` snippet.  You then want to parse the `<html/>` and grab those values to build up your `post` object?  Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

Although the title says **two way** data binding, from [your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678102/two-way-data-binding-for-html-contents-in-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment-23999827) I deduced that you want a single way data-binding.
If this is the case, this is the way to do it :

```
<div id="post">
  <div id="post-id">{{post.id}}</div>
  <div id="post-author">{{post.author}}</div>
  <div id="post-content">{{post.content}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: im not binding from `controller-->view`. I want the contents loaded from the server inside those `div` tags to go into model, so i can use it inside the controller for further processing... I dont get the `post` object directly from server.

Comment: so you basically want to parse some dom and insert that data into your controller as an angular model? I'm sorry, I just wanted to help (no need for downvotes), but it's hard to understand what you want if you are being vague